# Iterating through LocalDate range groovy list

Tags: groovy, localdate

This used to work under Groovy 3.x version but fails in 4.x

```
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2023, Month.JULY, 1)
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2023, Month.JULY, 31)
    LocalDate[] businessDates = (startDate..endDate).collect()
    businessDates.stream().forEach { print it }
```

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: java.time.LocalDate.next() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: get(java.time.temporal.TemporalField), wait(), now(), wait(long), now(java.time.Clock), now(java.time.ZoneId)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: java.time.LocalDate.next() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: get(java.time.temporal.TemporalField), wait(), now(), wait(long), now(java.time.Clock), now(java.time.ZoneId)
    at Main.run(Main.groovy:4)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: works for me - groovy 4.0.9

Comment: maybe you missed jar with LocalDate extensions?

Comment: Thanks - I am using jdk 11 within Eclipse IDE so it may have something to do with the classpath